# Javascript : Looping through nested window object to find particular element

Tags: javascript

I have a nested object .How do I change it to `while loop` or `for` loop. So that I can handle it for multiple levels.

```
var myObj = {};
if (window.dialogArguments && window.dialogArguments.previousWindow) {

    if (window.dialogArguments.previousWindow.dialogArguments &&
        window.dialogArguments.previousWindow.dialogArguments.previousWindow) {

        //Continue traversing

    }

} else {
    //Do something like :
    myObj = window.document.body;
}
```

`previousWindow` is an property of one window object which again holds `dialogArguments`.

Comment: So, if `window.dialogArguments.previousWindow` is falsy, you access its `document` property?

Comment: @Oriol- May bad. Typo mistake. Edited my question. When `window.dialogArguments` is falsy, then I will be accessing `window.document.body`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it well, you can use

```
var win, tmp = win = window;
while(tmp = tmp.dialogArguments)
    if(tmp = tmp.previousWindow)
        win = tmp;
var myObj = win.document.body;
```

or

```
var win, tmp = win = window;
while((tmp = tmp.dialogArguments) && (tmp = tmp.previousWindow))
    win = tmp;
var myObj = win.document.body;
```

or

```
var win, tmp = window;
do{ win = tmp; }
while ((tmp = tmp.dialogArguments) && (tmp = tmp.previousWindow))
var myObj = win.document.body;
```

Comment: I needed time to implement your solution. Which worked very smoothly. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please let me know what does this line do `while((tmp = tmp.dialogArguments)`. Assigning and comparing if not null or undefined?

Comment: Yes, it's an assignment, and assignments return the assigned value. Thus, the loop will continue until `dialogArguments` is falsy (`undefined`, `null`, `''`, `false`, `0`).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to keep stepping deeper into nested objects until you find a `window` without `dialogArguments` or `dialogArguments.previousWindow`.

You can loop on a variable that you continue to update with the deeper object until you find one that doesn’t have any further depth:

```
var myObj = {};
var currentWindow = window;

while (currentWindow.dialogArguments && currentWindow.dialogArguments.previousWindow) {
  currentWindow = currentWindow.dialogArguments.previousWindow;
}
else {
  myObj = currentWindow.document.body;
}
```